# Custom port forwarding to docker container

Tags: docker, iptables, portforwarding

I have a docker container C1 on host H1 which exposes a port that I can't map via the `docker run -p` option. I have to do the port forwarding myself via iptables.
I came up with the following rule.

```
iptables -t nat -I DOCKER 1 -p tcp --dport $HOST_PORT -j DNAT --to-destination $CONTAINER_IP_ADDRESS:$CONTAINER_PORT
```

- Case 1: When on H1 I can telnet with the IP of H1 to C1.
- Case 2: When on C1 I can't telnet with the IP of H1 to C1.

I am curious how `docker run -p` does the forwarding because Case 2 works with that option. I already analyzed the iptables rules that are created when using that, but wasn't able to get the same outcome.

Now I even started to do tcpdumps within the containers and found out that when doing the forwarding myself, packets are sent out to H1 but nothing comes back.

Can anyone tell me what docker does different when using the forwarding option?

EDIT 1:

It's not possible to use port mappings because Elastic Beanstalk V1 does not support that and I can't use V2.

I am doing the following:

- Case 1

  `root@H1: telnet $HOST_IP $HOST_PORT`
- Case 2

  `root@C1: telnet $HOST_IP $HOST_PORT`

Comment: Why isn't mapping the port using `-p` possible? Can you put in some example command lines with ip addresses so it's clear exactly what you're trying?

Comment: I updated the question. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: If docker daemon is started with `--iptables=false`, one have to manually use iptables.



[Nice article about Docker and IPTables](https://fralef.me/docker-and-iptables.html)